# Kendo UI (JS) grid with remote datasource, how can I save changes manually?

Tags: javascript, kendo-datasource, kendo-ui-grid

I have my Javascript Kendo UI grid, with a datasource that calls an ASP.Net MVC action on update. When I edit a row, and click on the check mark to confirm those changes, the remote update is executed at that moment.

What I'd like to do is to make the changes, "confirm them locally" and only save them (by calling sync()) when I click on a Save button at the end of my form. That way users can cancel the whole form,  including the changes they made on the grid. From reading the [DataSource API Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-autoSync), I though I just needed to set autoSync to false, but it makes no difference.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I found the answer. The grid can be configured to use [batch editing](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing). In that case, changes are done locally until the "Save Changes" button is pressed on the grid. There's also a saveChanges method on the grid object, which I'll be calling from my form button when it is clicked, just before submitting.